# can't install rails 3.1 "native extensions" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I try installing rails version 3.1 I get an error in the terminal:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/alonbond/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found
```

Gem files will remain installed in `/Users/alonbond/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3` for inspection.
Results logged to `/Users/alonbond/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out`

and then I try using a rails command:

```
Alon-Weissfelds-MacBook-Pro:~ alonbond$ rails -v

  Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

    You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Xcode from Mac App Store or GCC compiler https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer.

Usually Xcode solves all those problems. The GCC is not 100% compliant with all gems.